# TFBS predictions for yeast and pombe?

Tags: bioinformatics, transcription, genomes

Are there any resources out there for TFBS (transcription factor binding site) predictions for the yeast (*S. cerevisiae*) and *S. pombe* genomes? Even if these are only *de novo* predictions, I would like to have access to them.

Answer (score 2):

Try YEASTRACT http://www.yeastract.com/

> YEASTRACT (Yeast Search for Transcriptional Regulators And Consensus
>   Tracking) is a curated repository of more than 48333 regulatory
>   associations between transcription factors (TF) and target genes in
>   Saccharomyces cerevisiae, based on more than 1200 bibliographic
>   references. It also includes the description of 298 specific DNA
>   binding sites for more than a hundred characterized TFs.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old, but I think it might be useful to mention this:

You can also look at [RSAT](http://rsat.sb-roscoff.fr/RSAT_portal.html) (Regulatory Sequence Analysis Tools):

go in the Fungi portail, in "motif discovery" choose "[oligo-analysis](http://rsat-tagc.univ-mrs.fr/rsat/)"; there you can predict putative TFBS from upstream sequences for example. It detects repeated motifs. To be more specific of *Saccharomyces cerevisiae* or *S. pombe*, select these species in the "Background model" section.